# Android Emulator boots with different resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

At times my AVD boots up with a higher resolution than it is supposed to , I do not modify any of the settings before running it. Also when restarted it boots up with the right resolution. Although not critical it does waste sometime.

Comment: Are you sure you mean resolution and not DPI?

Comment: Good point , will check and post an update , but then the question would be why DPI changed when nothing was altered :-)

Comment: This happens to me too - no idea why, seems odd.

Comment: Same here, every once in a while it ignores my DPI settings. I just restart the emulator :)

Comment: Which version of the emulator are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it does but i just edited the details before launching and enabled launch from snapshot option. This did fix the issues and remembers previous settings.

Also if you are launching emulator from command like you can specify -scale 0.8 if you want it to be 80% of what you want.